# Passing input to xmllint as string not as file

Tags: python, xmllint

I need to call xmllint from python script and pass schema and input as string variables not as files. Is it possible?? if yes what is the format??

Answer (score 0):

`Xmllint` accepts only one of the 2 via stdin

Passing commands to `--shell` option

```
(echo "cat //tag1"; echo "cd /root/tag2"; echo "cat") | xmllint --shell test.xml
```

Passing document via stdin

```
cat test.xml | xmllint --xpath '//tag1' -
```